# When I create object fail by 422, how to do not add in the list with ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
  DEBUG: -------------------------------
  DEBUG: Ember             : 2.8.1
  DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.8.0
  DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.2.4
  DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.1.0
  DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I have model just call it `Product`, create new product also in the `/products` url. The page look like:

[image]

When I submit `create product form` will send actions `createProduct`:

```
actions: {
  createProduct() {
    let product = this.store.createRecord('product', {
      name: this.get('name'),
      ...
    });
    theWorkItem.save().then(()=> {
      ...
    }, ()=> {
      this.set('workItemErrors', theWorkItem.get('errors'));
    });
  },
...
```

The problem is when my product name is blank, server will return `422` and errors message will display in product form, but product list will add one, look like:
[image]

And this empty object not save in the server, just display in browser. I think if server return `422` the object not add to list.

So there is a good solution to this situation? Thanks.